# NTFS volumes read-only since update

Tags: mount, ntfs

Since yesterdays update to my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop system, all the NTFS volumes have become read-only. I haven't had time to research this fully yet; just seeing if anyone else is having the same problem. I see many old threads on this topic, but my system has been running perfectly until yesterday and there seem to be no new posts.

Permissions on those volumes looks good, but attempting to delete files or folders from Nemo fails and using rm in terminal line gives the message "read-only file system".

The system dual-boots with Windows 10 (which I use only rarely) and Windows now won't start, which may or not be related.

Comment: If would suggest scanning logs for when the `mount` was performed, and you'll see the reason. As Guangliang has stated in his answer, I'd suspect a 'dirty' state too and thus fsck (file system check) should be performed. Since NTFS is a windows fs, I'd probably do it in windows too. But I would scan logs for the reason; or if you're lazy then `umount` then `mount` via terminal so you can see the error message on your terminal (instead of view/grep..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem once.  The NTFS partition was mounted read-only.  The problem I had was that windows somehow mark the partition 'dirty'.  Boot back to the windows and did a check disk and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't booted into Windows for days (maybe even weeks) and Windows won't start at present, but I.ll follow up shortly.

Comment: You can download free and create a windows 10 installation usb stick (with a 16GB or bigger usb)..

Comment: Thanks, it was dirty file systems, although why four NTFS file systems should become dirty at the same time beats me! Fixed with Windows install disk (to check and fix Windows volume) then used Windows to fix the other volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `ntfsfix` command (part of the `ntfs-3g` package), which repairs some NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules a NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows. This might corrupt your Windows installation though, so it's not recommended, but if you're out of options, you could try this. I mention it because it made my SSD readable again by Ubuntu.

In your case, where you no longer have Windows 10 or 8 installed (or are no longer able to access it) but an NTFS partition was left in a hibernated state, it could also be worthwhile trying it.

You can use it with `sudo ntfsfix /dev/NTFS_partition` (for example `/dev/sdb1`) to get the partition to mount with full read/write access.